# How to show sum of data in folium featuregroups

Tags: pandas, folium, choropleth

**What I want to do:**

I want to show the sum of the selected data in the map. So if I check data2, data4 and data5, it'd show me the sum of these dataframes in the markers.

**What it does now:**

Now when I check data2, data4 and data5, it'll just show me the bottom one on top of each map, so in this case it'll show me data5.

[I want the sum of the data to show on my marker.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ealQ.png)

Here is my code:

```
#Reading data
df = pd.read_csv('C:/EzterLAPTOP/Ezter/source/Data/taulu2.csv', encoding='utf-8')
dictionary={'ä':'a','ö':'o','Ä':'A','å':'a'}
df.replace(dictionary, regex=True, inplace=True)

#Reading geojson
kunnat_geo = r'C:/EzterLAPTOP/Ezter/kuntarajat.geojson'
with open(kunnat_geo, encoding='utf-8') as kunnat_file:
    kunnat_json = json.load(kunnat_file)
    
#Cleaning data
df = df.rename(columns={'ALUE':'Kunta'})
df.drop(df.loc[df['lat']=='0.0'].index, inplace=True)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df = df[df.lat != 0]

#Creating map
map = folium.Map(location=[65,26], zoom_start=4, tiles='openstreetmap')
#Making a function that creates a choropleth map
def choromapping(name, col1):
    choropleth = folium.Choropleth(
        geo_data=kunnat_geo,
        name=name,
        data=df,
        columns=['Kunta',col1],
        key_on='feature.properties.Name',
        fill_color='OrRd',
        fill_opacity=0.8,
        line_opacity=0.2,
        legend_name=name,
        show=False
    ).add_to(map)

    choromarker = MarkerCluster().add_to(choropleth)
#Adding markers
    for i in range(0,len(df)):
        folium.Marker(
            [df.iloc[i]['lat'],
             df.iloc[i]['lng']],
            popup=(df.iloc[i][col1],
                   df.iloc[i]['Kunta']),
            tooltip=df.iloc[i]['Kunta']
        ).add_to(choromarker)
    
#Generating maps
choromapping('data1','MIELENTERVEYDEN KUNTOUTUSKOTIEN ASIAKKAAT VUONNA 2018')
choromapping('data2','KEHITYSVAMMALAITOKSEN_ASIAKKAAT_YHTEENSÄ_2018')
choromapping('data3','VANHAINKOTIEN_ASIAKKAAT_YHTEENSÄ_2018')
choromapping('data4','KOTIHOIDON_ASIAKKAAT_YHTEENSÄ_2018')
choromapping('data5','TEHOSTETUN_HOIDON_ASIAKKAAT_YHTEENSÄ_2018')
choromapping('data6','PALVELUASUMISEN_ASIAKKAAT_YHTEENSÄ_2018')
LayerControl().add_to(map)
map
```

[My data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KMejY8eVKHJkNZHfoccLC1ZS1iQ8bzzs/view?usp=sharing)
[My geojson](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19mJqEZ0i7IHHITKby6X8NMgx_r_Lo3Et/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Do you have the geojson file?

Comment: Edited it in there

Answer (score 0):

Changed a few things

1. using `map` as a variable name. `map` is a key function in core Python
2. there's no need for so many separate hits on dataframe with `iloc` just loop over data you need
3. excluded points where value is zero.  I assume you don't really want to put these into the layer
4. changed *popup* to be built from an f-string instead of passing a `tuple`
5. you note you want `sum`.  I didn't see your data could be aggregated `df.loc[:,["lat","lng","Kunta",'MIELENTERVEYDEN KUNTOUTUSKOTIEN ASIAKKAAT VUONNA 2018']].groupby(["lat","lng","Kunta"]).sum()` still returns 311 rows

```
import folium.plugins
import pandas as pd
import json
#Reading data
df = pd.read_csv('taulu2.csv', encoding='utf-8')
dictionary={'ä':'a','ö':'o','Ä':'A','å':'a'}
df.replace(dictionary, regex=True, inplace=True)

#Reading geojson
kunnat_geo = r'kuntarajat.geojson'
with open(kunnat_geo, encoding='utf-8') as kunnat_file:
    kunnat_json = json.load(kunnat_file)

    #Cleaning data
df = df.rename(columns={'ALUE':'Kunta'})
df.drop(df.loc[df['lat']==0.0].index, inplace=True)

#Creating map
m = folium.Map(location=[65,26], zoom_start=4, tiles='openstreetmap')
#Making a function that creates a choropleth map
def choromapping(name, col1):
    choropleth = folium.Choropleth(
        geo_data=kunnat_geo,
        name=name,
        data=df,
        columns=['Kunta',col1],
        key_on='feature.properties.Name',
        fill_color='OrRd',
        fill_opacity=0.8,
        line_opacity=0.2,
        legend_name=name,
        show=False
    ).add_to(m)

    choromarker = folium.plugins.marker_cluster.MarkerCluster().add_to(choropleth)
    #Adding markers
    for r in df.loc[df[col1].ne(0),["lat","lng","Kunta",col1]].to_dict(orient="records"):
        folium.Marker(
            [r['lat'],
             r['lng']],
            popup=f"({r[col1]},{r['Kunta']})",
            tooltip=r['Kunta']
        ).add_to(choromarker)

    
#Generating maps
choromapping('data1','MIELENTERVEYDEN KUNTOUTUSKOTIEN ASIAKKAAT VUONNA 2018')
choromapping('data2','KEHITYSVAMMALAITOKSEN_ASIAKKAAT_YHTEENSÄ_2018')
choromapping('data3','VANHAINKOTIEN_ASIAKKAAT_YHTEENSÄ_2018')
choromapping('data4','KOTIHOIDON_ASIAKKAAT_YHTEENSÄ_2018')
choromapping('data5','TEHOSTETUN_HOIDON_ASIAKKAAT_YHTEENSÄ_2018')
choromapping('data6','PALVELUASUMISEN_ASIAKKAAT_YHTEENSÄ_2018')
folium.map.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m
```

[image]